# How to include data from JSON to MySQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

**json data:**

```
 {"RECORDS": [{

      "id": 1,
      "name": "آذربایجان شرقی",
      "lat": 37.90357330,
      "long": 46.26821090
    },
    {
      "id": 2,

      "name": "آذربایجان غربی",
      "lat": 37.45500620,
      "long": 45.00000000
    },
    {
      "id": 3,

      "name": "اردبیل",
      "lat": 38.48532760,
      "long": 47.89112090
    },
    {
      "id": 4,

      "name": "اصفهان",
      "lat": 32.65462750,
      "long": 51.66798260
    },
    {
      "id": 5,

      "name": "البرز",
      "lat": 35.99604670,
      "long": 50.92892460
    },
    {
      "id": 6,

      "name": "ایلام",
      "lat": 33.29576180,
      "long": 46.67053400
    },
    {
      "id": 7,

      "name": "بوشهر",
      "lat": 28.92338370,
      "long": 50.82031400
    },
    {
      "id": 8,

      "name": "تهران",
      "lat": 35.69611100,
      "long": 51.42305600
    },
    {
      "id": 9,

      "name": "چهارمحال و بختیاری",
      "lat": 31.96143480,
      "long": 50.84563230
    },
    {
      "id": 10,

      "name": "خراسان جنوبی",
      "lat": 32.51756430,
      "long": 59.10417580
    },
    {
      "id": 11,

      "name": "خراسان رضوی",
      "lat": 35.10202530,
      "long": 59.10417580
    },
    {
      "id": 12,

      "name": "خراسان شمالی",
      "lat": 37.47103530,
      "long": 57.10131880
    },
    {
      "id": 13,

      "name": "خوزستان",
      "lat": 31.43601490,
      "long": 49.04131200
    },
    {
      "id": 14,

      "name": "زنجان",
      "lat": 36.50181850,
      "long": 48.39881860
    },
    {
      "id": 15,

      "name": "سمنان",
      "lat": 35.22555850,
      "long": 54.43421380
    },
    {
      "id": 16,

      "name": "سیستان و بلوچستان",
      "lat": 27.52999060,
      "long": 60.58206760
    },
    {
      "id": 17,

      "name": "فارس",
      "lat": 29.10438130,
      "long": 53.04589300
    },
    {
      "id": 18,

      "name": "قزوین",
      "lat": 36.08813170,
      "long": 49.85472660
    },
    {
      "id": 19,

      "name": "قم",
      "lat": 34.63994430,
      "long": 50.87594190
    },
    {
      "id": 20,

      "name": "كردستان",
      "lat": 35.95535790,
      "long": 47.13621250
    },
    {
      "id": 21,

      "name": "كرمان",
      "lat": 30.28393790,
      "long": 57.08336280
    },
    {
      "id": 22,

      "name": "كرمانشاه",
      "lat": 34.31416700,
      "long": 47.06500000
    },
    {
      "id": 23,

      "name": "کهگیلویه و بویراحمد",
      "lat": 30.65094790,
      "long": 51.60525000
    },
    {
      "id": 24,

      "name": "گلستان",
      "lat": 37.28981230,
      "long": 55.13758340
    },
    {
      "id": 25,

      "name": "گیلان",
      "lat": 37.11716170,
      "long": 49.52799960
    },
    {
      "id": 26,

      "name": "لرستان",
      "lat": 33.58183940,
      "long": 48.39881860
    },
    {
      "id": 27,

      "name": "مازندران",
      "lat": 36.22623930,
      "long": 52.53186040
    },
    {
      "id": 28,

      "name": "مركزی",
      "lat": 33.50932940,
      "long": -92.39611900
    },
    {
      "id": 29,

      "name": "هرمزگان",
      "lat": 27.13872300,
      "long": 55.13758340
    },
    {
      "id": 30,

      "name": "همدان",
      "lat": 34.76079990,
      "long": 48.39881860
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "name": "یزد",
      "lat": 32.10063870,
      "long": 54.43421380
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have a table named province & have **columns named**: `name`, `lat`, `long`

How can I add this data to my table as `name` and `lat` and `long` in Laravel?

**my table:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('provinces', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('lat');
            $table->text('long');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: use json_decode() function to convert it to array then mass assign it to laravel eloquent  [Laravel Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: I think you somehow need to tell us HOW you want to achieve this. Do you want to seed your database with this data? Or do you receive data like this more often and need a way to import json? or is it an on the fly process where you request json data and want to insert it into the database?

Comment: I just want to seed database with this data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one,

```
     foreach($data as $d){
         Province::create($d);
     }
```

or

```
     foreach($data['RECORDS'] as $d){
         Province::create($d);
     }
```

Note:- You need not to give id value if it is auto **increments** column means.